# css sprites for SVG images

Tags: css, svg

```
 <image x="20" y="20" width="300" height="80" xlink:href="logo.png" />
```

Is there any way to position the image using pixels? Like CSS sprites?

Comment: Position the image element inside the svg using pixels? or select a sprite from inside the logo.png (aka clipping)?

Answer (score -1):

You could position it using position:absolute

e.g.

```
img {
 position:absolute;
 top:20px;
 left:20px;
}
```

It will be positioned relative to it's parent container of that container has position:relative set on it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is an svg <image> element, not an html <img> element... so what you suggest will not work.

Comment: @ErikDahlström - Sorry, my bad.